# How can I optimize a query for selecting of the average value by groups?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
-----------
|  TABLE1 |
-----------
|id|class |
|1 |Class1|
|2 |Class2|
|3 |Class1|
|4 |Class1|
|5 |Class2|
|6 |Class3|
-----------

-----------------------
|       TABLE2        |
-----------------------
|id|table1_id|quantity|
|1 |    1    |    1   |
|2 |    1    |    2   |
|3 |    2    |    1   |
|4 |    2    |    1   |
|5 |    2    |    1   |
|6 |    4    |    1   |
|7 |    6    |    2   |
|8 |    6    |    1   |
-----------------------
```

I need to get all average quantity for every class. So I select all id's from table1 grouping by class, then I select avg(quantity) from table2 using WHERE IN by selected id's. But I have too much data and it works too long. How can I get solution which will work faster?

For my example I need next answer

```
-----------
class |avg|
-----------
Class1|1,5|
Class2| 1 |
Class3|1,5|
-----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select avg(table2.quantity), class
from table1, table2
where table1.id = table2.table1_id
group by table1.class
```

And you can also add and index on column table1_id. This will help making your query faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    T1.CLASS, 
    AVG(T2.QUANTITY) 
FROM 
    TABLE1 T1, TABLE2 T2 
    WHERE T1.ID = T2.TABLE1_ID
GROUP BY T1.CLASS
```

**Ensure the join columns are indexed properly.**

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.CLASS, AVG(T2.QUANTITY) AS 'AVG'
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.TABLE1_ID
GROUP BY T1.ID, T1.CLASS
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried INNER JOIN? For example:

```
SELECT T1.class, AVG(T2.quantity)
FROM TABLE2 T2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.table1_id
GROUP BY T1.class
```